# Deallocating the Vector memory after using it once?

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, destructor

I am looping n number of times and in each loop I want to allocate the memory to a new vector and after computing I want to deallocate the memory and again want to allocate new in the next loop.

**C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        vector<int> arr;
        int input;
        int i = 0;
        while ((cin >> input) && (i<n))
            arr.push_back(input), i++;

        for (auto i=arr.begin(), j=arr.begin()+1; i != arr.end()-1, j != arr.end(); i++, j++)
            if (*j < *i)
                cout << *j << " ";
            else
                cout << "-1" << " ";
        cout << "-1" << endl;

        arr.clear(); 
        arr.shrink_to_fit();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
2
5
4 2 1 5 3
6
5 6 2 3 1 7
```

**Expected Output**

```
2 1 -1 3 -1
-1 2 -1 1 -1 -1
```

Explanation:
Print the next immediate smaller elements for each element in the array, and if not so than print -1.

Testcase 1:
Array elements are 4, 2, 1, 5, 3. Immediate smaller of 2 is immediate smaller of 4, 1 is immediate smaller of 2, no immediate smaller of 1, 3 is immediate smaller of 5, and no immediate smaller for last element exists. So output is : 2 1 -1 3 -1.

My Output

```
2 1 -1 3 -1
2 -1 1 -1 -1   //error (wrong output)
```

When I am not looping and made it for single testcase than it is giving the desired output.

Program for single testcase

```
int main(){
   int n;
   cin>>n;
   vector <int> arr;
   ....
   ....
   ....
  arr.shrink_to_fit();
  return 0;
}
```

Input

```
6
5 6 2 3 1 7
```

Output

```
-1 2 -1 1 -1 -1
```

So there must be error while I am looping.

Comment: can you be more specific on your problem please?

Comment: when i made the program for single test case to run it is giving proper output but while making it for more than 1 testcase to run together it is giving wrong output as explained above

Comment: `arr` gets destroyed at the end of every iteration through the outermost `while` loop, so clearing it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: but still it is not giving the proper output and while i am running the testcases individually it is giving the proper output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your condition in the `while` loop (`(cin >> input) && (i<n)`).  You're reading the next input *before* you check to see if you've read in enough data.  So your first input actually reads six values

```
4 2 1 5 3 6
```

the second input reads the next digit, `5`, as the number of inputs, then reads those five as

```
6 2 3 1 7
```

which will give you the output you're getting.